# A linear transformation $T$ such that $(v_1, \dots, v_k, Tv_1, \dots, Tv_k)$ is a basis for $\mathbb F^{2k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Let $T: \mathbb R^{2k} \to \mathbb R^{2k}$ be a bijective linear transformation. We define a set
\begin{align*}
 S = \{ (v_1, \dots, v_k) \subset \mathbb R^{2k}: (v_1, \dots, v_k, Tv_1, \dots, Tv_k) \text{ is a basis for $\mathbb R^{2k}$ } \}.
\end{align*}
Is it possible to characterize the set $S$? In particular, the topological property, such as connectedness?

Comment: What kind of topology would you impose on this space? How would you define the distance between two bases?

Comment: Presumably, you could interpret $S$ as some kind of subspace of the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $Gr(k,\Bbb R^{2k})$, but you should say that this is what you have in mind

Comment: @Prism $(v_1,\dots,v_k,Tv_1,\dots,Tv_k)$ makes no sense if each $v_k$ is a scalar

Comment: Since it is finite dimension vector space, I was in mind some norm topology on $R^{2k}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: By your comments below, I can see the set is closed as intersections of closed sets. But how many connected components can it have?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit too long for a comment:

Per [this construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#The_Grassmannian_as_a_real_affine_algebraic_variety), we can identify the $k$ dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^k$ with the corresponding orthogonal projections, i.e. the symmetric $2k\times 2k$ matrices satisfying $X^2 = X$ and $\operatorname{tr}(X) = k$.  A set $B = (v_1,\dots,v_k)$ will be contained in $S$ if and only if the subspace $U$ spanned by $B$ satisfies
$$
U \cap T(U) = \{0\}
$$
This is in turn equivalent to the statement that the projection $X$ onto $U$ satisfies
$$
XTX = 0
$$
So, if you'd like to characterize the space of *$k$-dimensional subspaces* of $V$ satisfying $V = U \oplus T(U)$, then you could identify this set with the set of projection matrices $X$ given by
$$
\{X \in \Bbb R^{2k \times 2k} : X = X^T, X = X^2, \operatorname{tr}(X) = k, XTX = 0\}
$$